# Makefile variable to c program

Tags: c, makefile

Hello i need help with makefile variables.

```
make build //(compiler server) 
make run PORT=something //(run server on port something)
```

I need save this variable and post to the server.c and client.c Here is my Makefile

```
SERVER=server
CLIENT=client
FILES=src/server.c src/client.c
CFLAGS=-std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
CC=gcc
build:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SERVER) src/server.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(CLIENT) src/client.c
run:
        ./server
clean:
        $(RM) *.o src/$(CLIENT) src/$(SERVER
```

Comment: So how are you expecting to get the variable into the C program? Are you using getenv() to get it as an environment variable? Or expecting it on the command line? There's no code here, so no way to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: As mentioned we don't know how you intend for the program to read the variable. If from command line args you can simply change the `run` command to be `./server "$(PORT)"`

Comment: So i want read this variable than integer and for control write printf("Port is %d", PORT);

Answer (score 1):

A plausible outline for a compile-time decision about port number might be:

```
SERVER   = server
CLIENT   = client
SERVER.c = src/server.c
CLIENT.c = src/client.c
CFLAGS   = -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
PORT     = 9823
DFLAGS   = -DPORT=$(PORT)
CC       = gcc

all:   build

build: $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)

$(CLIENT): $(CLIENT.c)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -o $(CLIENT) $(CLIENT.c)

$(SERVER): $(SERVER.c)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) -o $(SERVER) $(SERVER.c)

run: $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
        ./$(SERVER)

clean:
        $(RM) *.o $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

The code for the client and the server contains code such as this, preferably in a common header:

```
#ifndef PORT
#define PORT 1234
#endif
```

and references PORT where the port number is needed.

If it is strictly a run-time decision, then maybe you use:

```
SERVER   = server
CLIENT   = client
SERVER.c = src/server.c
CLIENT.c = src/client.c
CFLAGS   = -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
PORT     = 9823
CC       = gcc

all: build

build: $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)

$(CLIENT): $(CLIENT.c)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(CLIENT) $(CLIENT.c)

$(SERVER): $(SERVER.c)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(SERVER) $(SERVER.c)

run: $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
        ./$(SERVER) -p $(PORT)

clean:
        $(RM) *.o $(CLIENT) $(SERVER)
```

You'd also need to tell the client to connect to the given port number, of course.  You should still have a default port number that is shared by both client and server in some common header.

You might use a hybrid of these solutions, where you define the default port number in the build process and use it in the `run` rule too.